# Getting selected text position but getting position is different for mozilla and chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting the selected text position value but the value is getting different for chrome and Mozilla. What to do so that I will get the same position value for both the browser?

```js
$( "#canvas-line").mouseup(function(ev) {
     mouseZ1 = ev.clientX;

      console.log('bottom = ' + mouseZ1);
    mouseA1 = ev.clientY;

    console.log("Right = " + mouseA1);
    document.getElementById("CanvasDown").value=mouseZ1;
    document.getElementById("CanvasRight").value=mouseA1;

 })

 .mousedown(function(ev) {
            mouseZ1 = ev.clientX;

             console.log('canvasLeft = ' + mouseZ1);
            mouseA1 = ev.clientY;
            console.log('Top = ' + mouseA1);

            document.getElementById("CanvasLeft").value=mouseZ1;
            document.getElementById("CanvasUp").value=mouseA1;
});
```

```css
::selection {
    background: yellow; }

::-moz-selection {
   background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Left<input id="CanvasLeft"></label>
  <label>Top<input id="CanvasUp"></label>
  <label>Right<input id="CanvasRight"></label>
  <label>Bottom<input id="CanvasDown"></label>
</div>

<div id="canvas-line">
The jury trial is one of the handful of democratic and we want to check the coordinate for all this items 
The jury trial is one of the handful of democratic and we want to check the coordinate for all this items S
The jury trial is one of the handful of democratic and we want to check the coordinate for all this items </div>

<div style="height:300px">
<!-- Just a dummy div to make the example area taller so
  the console calls don't cover the area right away -->
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `clientX` and `clientY` give you the mouse's position, relative to the element you clicked on. Unless you are clicking with pixel-perfect precision, you'll likely always get slightly different numbers each time the event handlers are called, no matter which browser you are in.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am trying to get the same position value of clientX and clientY in any browser, related to the element i clicked. for exm: If you select any text in chrome browser this will give you different value and if you select same text in mozilla you will get different value.

Comment: Like I said in my first comment, `clientx` and `clienty` are the position of the mouse, the only way to get the exact same number, regardless of which browser it is, it to click and release in the EXACT same place on the page. `clientx` and `clienty` have nothing to do with the text selection itself, only the position of the mouse at the time of the events. Differences in the way browsers render things might put the letters in slightly different places, but that doesn't matter because `clientx` and `clienty` are the mouse position, not the position of the selected text.

Comment: It appears that I forgot to post my second comment, or it got deleted, but I suggested looking into [`window.getSelection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) and [`Range.getClientRects`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getClientRects), they might help accomplishing what you are trying to do, but I can't say for sure because your question isn't clear on what exactly you are trying to accomplish, and you keep fixating on `clientx` and `clienty`, which I'm pretty sure are not the right tools for what you are probably trying to accomplish.